# Why can't I access my data from Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from Firestore and add it to a PieChart.
I can't figure out why I can't access my data

This is how data are stored in Firestore:

[image]

This is how I try to access it:

```
 private val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var chartdata: ArrayList<Measurements> = ArrayList()
private var chart: ScatterChart? = null

fun getCurrentUserID(): String {

    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    var currentUserID = ""
    if (currentUser != null) {
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }

    return currentUserID

}
```

```
 mFirestore.collection(Constants.MEASUREMENTS)
            .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                val userdata : ArrayList<Measurements> = ArrayList()
                val weekdata = ArrayList<Measurements>()
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty) {
                    for (journals in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        val displayData: Measurements = journals.toObject(Measurements::class.java)
                        userdata.add(displayData)
                        Log.e("Data for chart", journals.toString())
                    }
```

And I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeVz5.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help.

Comment: Please do not use links and images of code in questions. I embedded your Firebase structure but the error *TEXT* needs to be in the question instead of a link to an image. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, images or error messages are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: FYI, the reason that looks like an "error" in the log is because you are using `Log.e` - which is for logging errors. If you used `Log.d` (for debugging) it would look differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being fetched precisely that's why you can see all the document names in the logcat but as you are logging `DocumentSnapshot` object, that's why you are seeing the data in unusual format. Try logging `displayData` variables like:

```
Log.d("Data for chart", displayData.activity) // Use Log.d instead of Log.e
```

or `userdata` as an array and it will work as desired.

Comment: You were right, I get the data right. I needed to use `Log.d` instead of `Log.e`. I'm new to Kotlin. Thank you all